# I'm trying to set a default value for a TextField with data from a GetMapping call, but it doesn't get set. (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to set a default value to a TextField, with data obtained from a GetMapping call, but it does not set.

This is the information I get on the call

```
{
"id": 1,
"motivoConsulta": "Lorem",
"objetivosClinicos": "Lorem",
"otraInformacion": "Lorem",
"expectativas": "Lorem"
}
```

this is my code

```
class Iconsulta extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

   state = {
        info: [],
          form: {
             motivoConsulta: "",
             expectativas: "",
             objetivosClinicos: "",
             otraInformacion: "",
      },
   };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getInfo();
    }

getInfo = async () => {
 let res = await axios.get(
   `http://localhost:8080/expediente/findById/${this.props.id}`
    );
let data = res.data;
//console.log(data);
  this.setState({
      info: data,
   });
   console.log(this.state.info);
};

render() {
   return (
    <>
    <div className="form-section-consulta">
      <Title
        titulo="Informacion de la consulta"
        description="Motivacion y expectativas para el seguimiento"
      />

      <form onSubmit={this.manejadorSubmit}>
```

in this section is where I try to set the value with default Value, but it is not set with the data obtained from the API call

```
        <TextField
          className="input-txt"
          id="outlined-name"
          label="Motivo de la consulta"
          name="motivoConsulta"
          onChange={this.manejadorChange}
          defaultValue={this.state.info.motivoConsulta}
          //   helperText="Please enter your name"
        />
        <TextField
          className="input-txt"
          id="outlined-name"
          label="Expectativas"
          name="expectativas"
          onChange={this.manejadorChange}
          defaultValue={this.state.info.expectativas}

        />
        <TextField
          className="input-txt"
          id="outlined-name"
          label="Objetivos clinicos"
          name="objetivosClinicos"
          onChange={this.manejadorChange}
          defaultValue={this.state.form.objetivosClinicos}
        />
        <TextField
          className="input-txt"
          id="outlined-name"
          label="Otras Informaciones"
          name="otraInformacion"
          onChange={this.manejadorChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
    </>
   );
}
}
```

[this is my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Qt1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using your `TextField` components in [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) mode. This means, the `defaultValue` is set when your component mounts. At this time, the `GetMapping` call is still executing asynchronously and `this.state.info` is still empty.

After the `GetMapping` call returns, `this.state.info` will be updated, but the `defaultValue` for the text fields remains unchanged.

To fix this, use your components in [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) mode. Try replacing the `defaultValue` property for yoru `TextField` components with `value` - this is how most UI libraries distinguish between controlled and uncontrolled mode.